# what is the code to enable HTML input box that has been disabled, using javascript only, not jQuery

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById(boxname ).disabled=false;
```

doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById(boxname ).removeAtribute('disabled');
```

doesn't work.

What will work?  javascript only no jQuery etc. please.

```
<input id="boxname" />
```

Comment: Is `boxName` a variable ?

Comment: If not, it should be quoted as a string `getElementById("boxname")`

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `disabled` property to false is the way to go, you just have to first select the element. To do that, pass an ID *string* to `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById('boxname').disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById(boxname)
```

supposed to be

```
document.getElementById('boxname')
```

You are **missing the Quotes** in there. Id should be passed as a string.

**OR**

```
var boxname = 'boxname';

// Now you can pass in without any Quotes

 document.getElementById(boxname)
```

Comment: Unless you do `var boxname='boxname';` :)

Comment: I have tried every combination boxname,  'boxname',  "boxname" it's the disabled = false, disabled = "false" that doesn't work. when I disable with disabled= "true" it works, but trying to go back to enabled doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `enabled= true`  and `enabled=false`

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sometimes works when code placed in a particular place in the script
See my rotation code: http://jsfiddle.net/crownabhisek/kPybv/42/

Here, in the `script` section, in the `rotate()` function, when the `document.getElementById("rotation").removeAttribute("disabled");` is written in the 1st place where I've inserted a comment, it works. But in the 2nd place where I've inserted a comment it doesn't work.

No clue why.

**But the code to disable is indeed `document.getElementById("rotation").removeAttribute("disabled");` and it should actually work.**